# Where to add custom attribute field for product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

In magento 1.x version , we can add custom attribute field in catalog_product_flat_1 table.

But in magento 2, catalog_product_flat_1 table is missing.

On which table to save custom attribute field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depends on flat catalog enabled or not.

If flat catalog enabled then it will create table.

Mainly it will store like this way
you need to find that data-type, you will get from eav_attribute table.

Then based on you need to check catalog_product_entity_type(int,text)

Comment: how to enable catalog flat table?

Comment: go to Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Frontend

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-flat-catalog-magento-2.html